# Pass created post id from gform_after_submission action to gform_confirmation filter?

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I am trying to create a post when my [Gravity Form](https://www.gravityforms.com/) submits and redirect to the post permalink on form confirmation.

See below the function which creates my post/order when my form submits using the [`gform_after_submission`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_after_submission/) action.

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_1', [ $this, 'create_order' ], 10, 2 );

/**
 * ajax reload the cart summary
 * @param object $entry
 * @param array $form
 * @return void
 */
public function create_order($entry,$form)
{

    // convert keys to admin labels
    $entry = self::admin_labels($entry,$form);

    // get the current cart data array
    $data = self::data();

    // create an order array
    $order = [
        'post_author'   => User::$id,
        'post_content'  => json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES),
        'post_type'     => 'purchase-order',
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    ];

    // create order post using an array and return the post id
    $result = wp_insert_post($order);

    // if post id and is not a wp error then
    if($result && !is_wp_error($result)) {

        // get the id
        $post_id = $result;

        // update gform meta with the order id
        gform_update_meta($entry['id'],'order_id',$post_id );

        // create our order reference number
        $order_ref = str_pad($post_id,5,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

        // create our title
        $title = 'Order #' . $order_ref;

        // new order array of updates
        $order = [
            'ID'            => $post_id,
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_name'     => $order_ref
        ];

        // update the order with new details
        wp_update_post($order);

        // set the the order type as purchase order
        wp_set_post_terms($post_id,'purchase-order','order_type');

        // update all the order custom fields
        self::update_order_fields($post_id,User::$id,$data,$entry);

        // unset cookie
        unset($_COOKIE['wm_cart']);

        // re set cookie and backdate to end cookie
        setcookie('wm_cart', null, -1, '/');

    }

}
```

The above code works good and creates my order/post fine.

I am then trying to redirect to the newly created post when the form confirmations fires.

So i'm using [`gform_confirmation`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation/) filter but I can't find away to the pass the id to here.

```
add_filter('gform_confirmation_1', [ $this, 'order_confirmation' ], 10, 4 );

/**
 * ajax reload the cart summary
 * @param array $confirmation
 * @param array $form
 * @param object $entry
 * @param array $ajax
 * @return array $confirmation
 */
public function order_confirmation($confirmation,$form,$entry,$ajax)
{

    // get order id from gform get meta
    $post_id = gform_get_meta($entry['id'],'order_id');

    // confirmation
    $confirmation = array( 'redirect' => get_permalink( $post_id ) );

    // return confirmation
    return $confirmation;

}
```

I cant redirect in the submission because my form is AJAX, and the redirect just happens in the ajax call, so I am having to try to use `$confirmation` to modify the redirect.

Can anyone help me figure out a safe way to redirect to my newly created post via the submission?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry object is available in both hooks, so how about saving the created post ID as meta on the entry with [`gform_update_meta()`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_update_meta/):

```
gform_update_meta( $entry->id, 'order_id', $post_id );
```

Then retrieving it in the confirmation, using [`gform_get_meta()`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_get_meta/):

```
$post_id = gform_get_meta( $entry->id, 'order_id' );
```

Comment: I've updated my code with your idea. The id's return correct it's doesn't seem to get saved properly.

Comment: I think confirmation is just running too early before. `gform_get_meta` is running before `gform_update_meta` has run. So it redirects to the default `hello world` post permalink.

Comment: Because the correct meta key and meta value is saved in `gf_entry_meta` database table.

Comment: So I used `gform_pre_handle_confirmation` instead of `gform_after_submission` and the timing now works with you idea. Many Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So basically I managed get [Jacob Peattie](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/39152/jacob-peattie) idea working by using..

```
add_action('gform_pre_handle_confirmation', [ $this, 'create_order' ], 10, 2 );
```

instead of...

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_1', [ $this, 'create_order' ], 10, 2 );
```

But you can't specify the form with `gform_pre_handle_confirmation` action so I had put this check in my `create_order` function to make sure this only runs for this form.

```
// only allow this method to handle form 1
if (!array_key_exists('id', $form) || $form['id'] <> 1) {
    return;
}
```